# How to save images in firebase firestore using flutter android?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter android application that uses `firebase firestore` as a backend service. I am stuck on how to save images to the database. Does anyone have an idea on how to store images in `firestore`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Firestore (a document database) for that? When I need to store images, I do so in Storage: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage. Also part of Firebase, but more suited for storing binary data.

Comment: Is the `firebase storage` suitable for storing documents as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store images or files in general.
I guess right now you have used the firebase_core or firebase auth package.

Firebase also has a [firebase_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage) package which you can use easily to store images

check out this [example](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage/example)